# Center with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've this code :

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Test 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Test 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Test 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Test 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want my links to be center vertically and horizontally. Plus they have to fit the `<li>` container.

Can you inherit the `flex-grow` property ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: If you add `text-align: center` the links get into center, what-else do you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the `li` and `a` flex too

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
}

a {
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Test 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Test 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Test 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Test 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `text-align: center` to your `li` to center it, and a `flex: 1` to your `li` and `height: 100%` to your `a` to make it occupy 100% of the height of its parent.

Try this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
}

a {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Test 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Test 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Test 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Test 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that each list item(the child) is also containing a child(the link).

So add `display:flex;` to the `li` also, then you can use flex properties on the `li`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

a {
  display: block;
  align-self:center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Test 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Test 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Test 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Test 5</a></li>
</ul>
```